# Error by installing pydev into Eclipse

Tags: pydev

I have to install pydev plugin into eclipse. I did the following steps: help -> install new Software and I have used the pydev updates site but I became this error message:

> "HTTP Server Unknown HTTP Response Code
>   (302):http://pydev.org/updates/content.xml HTTP Server Unknown HTTP
>   Response Code (302):http://pydev.org/updates/content.xml General
>   connection error with response code=302"

I also tried to install with the Eclipse Market without success. I can install another plugins but just Pydev don't work. I really don't know how to manage it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That link is a redirect... try putting the direct url to see if it works (currently): https://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/5.6.0 -- visit http://www.pydev.org/updates/ to get the latest link for the current version.

Comment: It worked but there is another message error during the Installation process: " Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev,5.6.0.201703221358.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\A67779~1\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile5749018230321821140.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\A67779~1\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile5749018230321821140.jar".           Can someone please help me to fix it?

Comment: Which Eclipse version are you using?

Comment: Oh, that'll definitely not work for such an ancient version of Eclipse (it has bugs related to the signature of jars which make it incompatible with newer releases). If you really need such an old version, you need to get an older release -- you can browse urls at: http://www.pydev.org/update_sites/ --
 http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html has the list of versions for older releases -- for helios (3.6) it'd be 2.8.2.